# Italics in code markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This question: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23131/pseudo-code-for-pid-control-of-only-the-left-wheel-of-a-2wheeled-mobile-robot
(unfortunately, it is closed) has a large code block.  And inside this code block a bunch of text is rendered as italics when it should not be.

Here is a test of italics in a code block:

This is the pseudo code:

```
%PID parameters

Kp = 10; Ki = 1; Kd = 100;

%Auxiliary variables

integral = 0; derivative = 0; last_error = 0; last_time = system_time()

%System values to controll

set_value = 50; %velocity in mm/s
encoder_resolution = 200 %number of pulses in 360º 
weel_perimeter = 100; %100mm of wheel perimeter

%Calculation of mm/pulse of encoder (this is the first code I have to complete and 
%I believe the answer to be the one I show below even though I have no feedback)

1. ______________________________

%loop of control of the system utilizing PID control

while true
    real_value = read_left_encoder();
    delta_T = system_time() - last_time;

    %Error calculation (in this one I was told I was wrong, but I don't understand why)

    2. ______________________________
    integral = integral + error; %Ki
    derivative = error - last_error(); %Kd

    % Calculate speed ajustmant with PID
    
    Kvel = Kp*error + Ki*integral*deltaT + Kd*derivative/delta_T

    %Update system's speed adjustment with new error (Once again in this one I was told I was wrong but with no explanation)

    3. ______________________________

    %Update feedback variables of PID control

    last_error = error;
    last_time = system_time();

    (Here I didn't get any feedback on my answer)
    4. ______________________________
```

1. `encoder_factor = weel_perimeter/encoder_resolution`
2. `error = realvalue * encoder_factor - set_value`
3. `left_motor = const_vel - Kvel`
4. `delta_T = 0`

Comment: Ha of course it works fine here.

Comment: Edited the question to include the exact source (including trailing comments) because I noticed the triple backticks that SHOULD be ending the code block were actually included at the end of your original post. I thought maybe it was some issue with the original question's post using triple backticks to make code sections in the trailing list doing something weird. The formatting looks fine here and in the edit history for the question, but when you look at the [original version of the question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/revisions/23131/1) you can see the formatting issues.

Comment: For the original version link above you can see some of the text is italics, bold, or both. In the [version history seen here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/posts/23131/revisions) you can scroll to the bottom to see the "history" of the first version with no flaws. That it works there, and here on the meta, but not on Robotics makes me think it's some issue with the formatter specific to the main Robotics site.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that because the term `PID` was the first thing in the code block, the syntax highlighter was trying to apply the `PID` syntax highlighting rules to the block.  But there are none, so it defaulted back to normal markdown.

Other moderators helped figure this out and the question is now fixed.  (By putting `lang-none` after the backticks).  But this still seems like a strange bug to me.

Comment: I don't have anything else to add to this! This is correct. Thanks for explaining it for me.

Comment: @Catija - This is the only way I know to reach out to you - can you please take a look at [this question](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1483/9720)?